# Bus input and output to multiple modules in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am creating a module xxx 16 times and each module has a 16 bit bus input and 1 bit output.

```
wire [15:0]    a[0:15];
wire [0:15]    o;
genvar i;
generate
for(i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin: n_loop
  xxx yy(
    .in    (a[i]);
    .out   (o[i]);
  );
  end
endgenerate
```

will this connects all the `a0`...`a14` wire buses, each of 16 bits to the 16 modules and also will the modules output be connected to the o bus?

Comment: Should o not be wire [15:0].

Answer (score -1):

i dont know what your module xxx looks like so it is really hard to comment on the instantiation for it. i am hoping you have implemented some type of multiplexer to select the single bit you are having on wire o.

Your question is a little confusing but if i think you are trying to have a 16 bit input and a 1 bit output you want something like this :

```
wire [15:0]    a[0:15];
wire o;
genvar i;
generate
for(i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin: n_loop
// o would only be one bit selected by mux in your xxx module
  xxx yy(.in(a[i]), .out(o));
  end
endgenerate
```

Is this what you meant by your question?

If not just leave a more descriptive comment and I will try to help!